# Where does Nominatim get its address info?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

Till now, I was using the Nominatim API to fetch landmark information from but recently, I've downloaded the OpenStreetMaps database, and tried to make my own dataset, so I would not rely so heavily on Nominatim services. I managed to extract from the OSM database the needed information (nodes tagged with amenity for example), but I realized, that while I was querying for amenities through Nominatim, it returned a bunch of address info, which is nowhere to be found in the OSM database.

Example:

Reverse geocoding of a hotel from Spain using Nominatim:
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&osm_type=N&osm_id=1207098527

The data that is attached to the same node used to reverse geocode in OSM:
http://open.mapquestapi.com/xapi/api/0.6/node/1207098527

While Nominatim gives me **Suburb, Pedestrian, City, County, State, etc.** information, this node in OSM contains only a **name** tag, and a **tourism** tag.

Does anyone know, where is Nominatim getting the additional data it uses to display its information from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nominatim does not just look at individual objects but gathers information from multiple objects instead. Look at the [information Nominatim knows about "HOTEL LA MORADA MAS HERMOSA"](http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=12835682): There are:

- the [node](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1207098527), lacking all address information ([feel free to improve this!](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_guide), at least [house number and street](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:addr) should be added)
- a [nearby street](http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/48902253)
- the [suburb](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1675832647) the hotel is located in
- the [city](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/340756)

... and so on.

Remember, OSM is a spatial database. Instead of attaching all information to each individual object one can do spatial queries in order to gather various kinds of additional information.

Comment: Marked this as correct, as it answers my initial question, but: I've checked the first link you provided, which indeed returns the desired data by me, but I still don't know how to retrieve it manually, by using only the database provided by OpenStreetMaps to me. If you could point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful:)

Comment: The adress that the Nominatim api, and also your link provides, is the way with the following id:  48902253. But how can Nominatim connect this way with the specific node? I presume it must be connected by relations somewhere, am I right? If yes, if you could point me to an example, of how Nominatim connects the ways and nodes, I would resolve the problem from there.:)

Comment: The node is not part of any relations, otherwise they would be listed [here](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1207098527).

Of course you can retrieve these informations manually from the OSM database but this isn't trivial. Nominatim (and other [search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines)) do lots of pre-processing for building hierarchies and retrieving these information. A single query won't suffice. If you really want to know how Nominatim does it then take a look at [its code](https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim). Unfortunately there is not much documentation.